# Yourkit vs Java Mission Control

Tags: yourkit, jmc

I have a question about Yourkit and Java Mission Control....

I used Yourkit 7 years ago to profile a J2EE Application, now I am working for another project and I have to profile an application, this project does not have license for Yourkit.

During researching the internet, I found the Java Mission Control, it seems to me, it nearly has the same features of Yourkit from 7 years ago.

So my question is, does the latest version of Yourkit does something more then JMC so I can argument my project to argument to pay the licenses....

Thx for answers....